# ApplicationDbContext Seed starts only if I go to Person Controllers index action in ASP .NET MVC 5.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, seed

I run the Web Application `HomeController.Index()` action is run. Then I go to `Person.Index()`(it is at the bottom of this post) via browser then and only then `Migrations.Configuration.Seed()` is invoked. But I want it to happen at the application start.

Configuration:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Migrations {
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApplication2.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext> {
        public Configuration() {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seed started");
            //  System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext> s = new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>();
            // s.InitializeDatabase(context);
            if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
                var persons = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

                persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.Meetings.Any()) {
                var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
            };


                meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.AddOrUpdate(meeting));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            if (!context.Statuses.Any()) {
                var statuses = new List<Status> {
                new Status{Name = "OK"},
                new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
            };



                statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.AddOrUpdate(status));
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            //Users Seeding

            if (!context.Users.Any()) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("USER SEED");
                try {
                    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                    //why user is not created
                    var user1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    var user2 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "emp", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    manager.Create(user1, "admin");
                    manager.Create(user2, "emp");

                    context.SaveChanges();
                } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION"); }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

IdentityModels.cs

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CONSTRCTOR");
          // Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
        }



        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using WebApplication2.Migrations;
using WebApplication2.Models;


namespace WebApplication2 {
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application_Start");
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

}

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
   <!-- <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Migrations.Configuration, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The `Person` controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers {
    public class PersonController : Controller {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Person
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View(db.Persons.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Person/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            if (person == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: Person/Create
        public ActionResult Create() {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Person/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,CellNumber,SecondaryPhoneNumber,Address,BirthDate,Pesel,Notes")] Person person) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: Person/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            if (person == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            //Moj kod
            //Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
            //ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
            //ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
            ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Statuses, "Id", "Name", person.StatusId);



            //Moj kod
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: Person/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,CellNumber,SecondaryPhoneNumber,Address,BirthDate,Pesel,Notes,StatusId")] Person person) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: Person/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            if (person == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: Person/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) {
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            db.Persons.Remove(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing) {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        public string formatPhoneNumber(string number) {
            Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
            return rgx.Replace(number, "");
        }

        public ActionResult Call(int id, string number) {
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            string formattedNumber = "tel:+48" + formatPhoneNumber(number);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NUMBER " + formattedNumber);
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = formattedNumber;
            proc.Start();
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new Person { Id = id });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your application start, do something like `new ApplicationDbContext ().Database.Initialize(true);`

Comment: @MohamadBataineh But would then I would Seed it twice --> when I go to Person controller?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your PersonController where it would invoke a second seed.

Comment: Me too, but it did after going to its Index action.

Comment: @MohamadBataineh it seeds when I go to PersonController if and only if in Application_Start is:  `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());`

Comment: @MohamadBataineh Your advice worked I have only one seed at startup but why it behaved in manner described above before?

Comment: SetInitializer dosent run until there is activity within the context/database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Database.SetInitializer` runs whenever there is activity within your context. You going to your PersonController would set off the `SetInitializer` you have in your Application Start.

Add `new ApplicationDbContext ().Database.Initialize(true);` In replacement of your Initializer.

Comment: When I leave: `new ApplicationDbContext ().Database.Initialize(true);` without: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());` it doesn't ever initilize database when I leave both database is initilized at the startup.

Comment: @Yoda Read the documentation for both of these, they're helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I read about them before and some tutorials but this is just what happpens(my first comment). When I leave only `...Initilize(true);` is not enough when I leave both it works. Don't know why, but thanks.

Comment: Thank you. To be honest this was part of other problem. I thought that users are not added because seed method didn't run but when it runs: could you please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354751/no-users-have-been-created-during-seed-method-using-usermanager-in-asp-net-mvc?noredirect=1#comment39532147_25354751