# No users have been created during Seed method using UserManager in ASP .NET MVC applications

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

When the `Seed`method runs, records/objects are added to my database.

Every object is added as it should till I try add users to my application(at the bottom of `Seed` method). No one is added. Also there is lot of `SQL` exceptions thrown posted at the bottom. They are thrown even if `Seed` method is empty.

How to add users to Entity Framework managed database? I created my code following Scott Allen's tutorial.

```
 protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seed started");//IT WORKS

            if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
                var persons = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

                persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.Meetings.Any()) {
                var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
            };


                meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.AddOrUpdate(meeting));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            if (!context.Statuses.Any()) {
                var statuses = new List<Status> {
                new Status{Name = "OK"},
                new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
            };



                statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.AddOrUpdate(status));
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
           //EVERYTHING TILL NOW WORKS
            //Users Seeding

            if (!context.Users.Any()) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("USER SEED");
                try {
                    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                    //why user is not created
                    var user1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    var user2 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "emp", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    manager.Create(user1, "admin");
                    manager.Create(user2, "emp");

                    context.SaveChanges();
                } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION"); }
            }


        }
```

---

**EDIT:**

I added some prints to the section where I add users also I posted output with some SQL exceptions.

```
if (!context.Users.Any()) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("USER SEED");
            try {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1");
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                //why user is not created
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2");
                var user1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                var user2 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "emp", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
                manager.Create(user1, "admin");
                manager.Create(user2, "emp");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4");
                context.SaveChanges();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("5");
            } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION"); }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("6");
```

Output:

```
CONSTRCTOR
CONSTRCTOR
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
CONSTRCTOR
Seed started
USER SEED
1
2
3
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/14/ROOT-1-130527942456023568): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
4
5
6
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/14/ROOT-1-130527942456023568): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

---

EDIT 2

Here is `CONSTRUCTOR`:

**Models.IdentityModels.cs**

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CONSTRCTOR");

        }



        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Migrations.Confriguration.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication2.Migrations {
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApplication2.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext> {
        public Configuration() {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {
            /*
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seed started");
                        if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
                            var persons = new List<Person> { 
                         new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
                         new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
                        };

                            persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person));
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        if (!context.Meetings.Any()) {
                            var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                            new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
                        };


                            meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.AddOrUpdate(meeting));
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        if (!context.Statuses.Any()) {
                            var statuses = new List<Status> {
                            new Status{Name = "OK"},
                            new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
                        };



                            statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.AddOrUpdate(status));
                            context.SaveChanges();

                        }*/
            //Users Seeding

            if (!context.Users.Any()) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("USER SEED");
                try {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1");
                    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                    //why user is not created
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2");
                    var user1 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    var user2 = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "emp", Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
                    manager.Create(user1, "admin");
                    manager.Create(user2, "emp");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4");
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("5");
                } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION"); }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("6");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using WebApplication2.Migrations;
using WebApplication2.Models;


namespace WebApplication2 {
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application_Start");

           Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
           new ApplicationDbContext().Database.Initialize(true);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
   <!-- <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Migrations.Configuration, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

**EDIT 3(partialy solved problem)**: This below did the job. But why the way introduced in MVC 5(User Manager above) does not work?

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE " + !context.Users.Any());

            if (!context.Users.Any()) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INSIDE");
                var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
                var users = new List<ApplicationUser> { 
                        new ApplicationUser{UserName = "admin", PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("admin")}
                        };

                users.ForEach(user => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

---

Current version of Migrations/*(directory)*/.Configuration.cs with `Seed` method inside:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Migrations {
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApplication2.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext> {
        public Configuration() {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seed started");
            if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
                var persons = new List<Person> { 
                         new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
                         new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
                        };

                persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (!context.Meetings.Any()) {
                var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                            new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
                        };


                meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.AddOrUpdate(meeting));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            if (!context.Statuses.Any()) {
                var statuses = new List<Status> {
                            new Status{Name = "OK"},
                            new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
                        };



                statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.AddOrUpdate(status));
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            //Users Seeding
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BEFORE " + !context.Users.Any());



            if (!context.Users.Any()) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INSIDE");
                var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
                try {
                    var users = new List<ApplicationUser> { 
                        new ApplicationUser{PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("TestPass44!"), Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4444@wp.pl"},
                        new ApplicationUser{PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("TestPass44!"), Email = "informatyka4445@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4445@wp.pl"}
                        };

                    users.ForEach(user => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user));

                    context.SaveChanges();
                } catch (DbEntityValidationException e) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EXC: ");
                    foreach (DbEntityValidationResult result in e.EntityValidationErrors) {
                        foreach (DbValidationError error in result.ValidationErrors) {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you run in debug? what is status of Users.Any ?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("USER SEED");` prints on the console so there is no users and it runs till this point.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana Please look at the edit I posted the output and edited fragment of the code which adds users. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless you explicitly call Database Initialize, a seed method won't run at runtime.  (alternatively, at design time you can use db migrations in nuget command line to also case the seed method to execute).

Comment: @ErikPhilips `Seed` method runs at startup. That is why I get output on my console.->see edit

Comment: @ErikPhilips but I get lot of exceptions shown in the edit of the OP.

Comment: If you're worried about the exceptions you should post where-ever your `CONSTRCTOR` debug statements are.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thank you. I posted in EDIT2 all I think might be helpful. I do not know what throws those exceptions. If I can help, explain, add anything please tell me.

Comment: @Yoda Bit silly question but what database are you looking at? Just for verification?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006.mdf` TABLE: AspNetUsers

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana EDIT 3 in OP -> The old way of adding users did the job but in Scott Allen's(Pluralsight) MVC 5 tutorial videos he said that this UserManager was introduced recently... it did not work.

Comment: @Yoda I am equally confused. Did you enable migrations through PM console. Can you try updating through PM console as well and see what difference you see?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana I have set automigration to true in the code also I've done `update-database` in PM few times and even changed database from this long named one(2 posts above) to `AppDb`. I must go sleep it is 4:31 am here. Thank you for help.

Comment: Code it great, but much if it is out of context, I don't know what class the seed method is in, I don't what class your Edit 3 code is part of.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Seed method is in `Migrations.Configuration.cs` I pasted full content of this file in EDIT2. The piece of code in the EDIT3 is in the Seed method and it replaced use of `UserManager`. I paste full `Migrations.Configuration.cs` in EDIT4 in current version.

Comment: @ErikPhilips If I can help, explain anything in any way please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Any news? What was it? I have the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the current manager from the context:

```
var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Be sure to inlude the namespace for this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

Using this manager instance, you should be able to create a user correctly.