# Azure Dbuser limited privileges entity framework master error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

When I connect to my database with an account which has only access to that database in azure I get the following error: `Login failed for user 'webapp'.` I get it on the following piece of code on line 47:

```
Line 45:         }
Line 46:         public ApplicationDbContext()
Line 47:           : base("DefaultConnection")
Line 48:         {
Line 49:             Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new NullDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

My visual studio shows this: `The server principal "myusername" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.`
I've seen the issue more on SO but haven't found an answer yet. I tried to set initializer to null as [Suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354718/applicationdbcontext-seed-starts-only-if-i-go-to-person-controllers-index-action)

Also tried to disable it in the web.config, but no success.
[Suggested here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx)

```
<contexts>
  <context type=" Models.ApplicationDbContext, MyAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" />
</contexts>
```

I don't want the entity framework to use dbuser to access the master table. How can I prevent this?